# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, junit4, hamcrest, equinox

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5987e932 wants to load interface org.hamcrest.Matcher. A different interface with the same name was previously loaded by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5aa6202e. (org.hamcrest.Matcher is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5aa6202e, parent loader 'platform')

I am trying to update eclipse-4.23 and after adding new composite and orbit repo I am getting this issue.

Comment: Find out where `org.hamcrest.Matcher` is used in which version and then make sure to require the same version.

Comment: Thanks @howlger.

I am using two p2 repo like orbit and composite -
in orbit I have this *org.hamcrest_2.2.0* & in composite this *org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0*

this both jar has same org.hamcrest.Matcher class, this is causing this issue.

help me to exclude this from p2 repo ?

Comment: How do you build your plugin and how do you use these two p2 repos? You should use a target platform definition file where you can specify which installation units of which p2 repos are used. Please show your `pom.xml` file and target definition file if any.

Comment: Got resolved this just replacing *org.hamcrest*  to *org.hamcrest.library*  in my manifest require bundle.